# Develop an app with GitHub and Heroku without installing anything locally?

Tags: django, heroku, github

I have an open-source Django/Heroku webapp on GitHub, and I want other people to be able to easily deploy their own version to the web and tinker with minor changes. I wonder if this could all be done in the browser, since GitHub has a web-based text editor with basic language support, and the new [Heroku Button](https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2014/8/7/heroku-button) feature allows you to click a button to do first-time setup of an app on Heroku.

But if I want to edit that app afterward and then re-deploy, it seems I need to install the Heroku toolbelt, edit the files locally, and push. Or is there a simple browser-based way, like editing the files in GitHub's web UI and clicking a re-deploy button?